# running Rails console in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just gone live with my first Rails site, but now I have a problem. When I run the project in development mode on my IDE I can run the console to something like:

`User.first.name='whatever'` to change a users name.

How do I accomplish the same task on a live site in production mode?

Answer (score 208):

if you're running rails 3.0 or greater, you can also use

```
rails console production
```

production can of course be substituted with `development` or `test` (value is `development` by default)

Adding the option `--sandbox` makes it so that any changes you make to your database in the console will be rolled back after you exit

If this isn't working for you, you may need to try

```
bundle exec rails console production
```

If you are actually trying to run the rails console on your production server, try googling "run rails console [your cloud hosting provider]" e.g. "run rails console heroku"

***As of Rails 6 you need to use***

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c
```

or

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails c
```

depending on your setup

Comment: For anyone else stuck in the ice age of rails versions, for me in 2.3.2 it was `script/console production`

Answer (score 60):

Pretty easy:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails console
```

Answer (score 23):

If you have already deployed your site to the server, you can also use:

```
bundle exec rails console production
```

...in the webroot of your rails app. That is if you haven't installed the rails package directly on the server yet or if you want to run console within the context of your web app.

Comment: ...especially so in Rails 4.

Answer (score 11):

Try below command.

```
  rails c -e production
```

Answer (score 6):

Note: This answer assumes you are using Heroku as your hosting service.

It depends on what hosting service you are using. For Heroku, you can go to your terminal and type in

```
heroku run rails console
```

This will load up the rails console for your production site and will allow you to create records for your live site.

You can also look into [seeding a database](https://gist.github.com/thejourneydude/02f8831e640aa3270a9b) but that is generally meant for testing. RailsCasts has some videos on the topic but they are a bit outdated.

Answer (score 5):

With Rails 6.1.6 on AlmaLinux8, the below command worked for me.

```
bundle exec rails console -e production
```

Answer (score -1):

today with rails 6 run in console `RAILS_ENV=production rails console`